# First n characters of a string, even if it is shorter than n?

Tags: c#, .net, substring

Say I have string `s`. I want to return `s` if `s` is shorter than `n` characters, and otherwise return `s.Substring(0, n)`.

What's the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 9):

The quickest way I know is:

```
var result = s.Length < n ? s : s.Substring(0, n);
```

Comment: Simple but inefficient: `var result = new string(s.Take(n).ToArray());`

Answer (score 4):

Tiny bit slower than [Superbest's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29467155/3999513):

```
string result = s.Substring(0, Math.Min(s.Length, n));
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to write a couple of extension methods.

Then you can just use it like `string result = sourceString.Left(10);`

```
public static class StringExt
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the first <paramref name="count"/> characters of a string, or the entire string if it
    /// is less than <paramref name="count"/> characters long.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="self">The string. Cannot be null.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The number of characters to return.</param>
    /// <returns>The first <paramref name="count"/> characters of the string.</returns>

    public static string Left(this string self, int count)
    {
        Contract.Requires(self != null);
        Contract.Requires(count >= 0);

        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
        // ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>().Length <= count);
        // ReSharper restore PossibleNullReferenceException

        if (self.Length <= count)
            return self;
        else
            return self.Substring(0, count);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the last <paramref name="count"/> characters of a string, or the entire string if it
    /// is less than <paramref name="count"/> characters long.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="self">The string. Cannot be null.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The number of characters to return.</param>
    /// <returns>The last <paramref name="count"/> characters of the string.</returns>

    public static string Right(this string self, int count)
    {
        Contract.Requires(self != null);
        Contract.Requires(count >= 0);

        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
        // ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>().Length <= count);
        // ReSharper restore PossibleNullReferenceException

        if (self.Length <= count)
            return self;
        else
            return self.Substring(self.Length - count, count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is shorter *or equal to* the desired length, just return the string.  Do not call `Substring` just to return the entire string.

```
var result = s.Length <= n ? s : s.Substring(0, n);
```